# PySpark: cast "string-integer" column to IntegerType

Tags: python, datetime, types, pyspark

I have a column with `datetime.datetime` objects as its contents. I'm trying to use `pyspark.sql.Window` functionality, which requires a numeric type, not datetime or string. So my plan is to convert the `datetime.datetime` object to a UNIX timestamp:

Setup:

```
>>> import datetime; df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
... [(datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 17, 19, 0, 15),),
... (datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 17, 19, 0, 16),)], ['dt'])
>>> df
DataFrame[dt: timestamp]
>>> df.dtypes
[('dt', 'timestamp')]
>>> df.show(5, False)
+---------------------+
|dt                   |
+---------------------+
|2018-01-17 19:00:15.0|
|2018-01-17 19:00:16.0|
+---------------------+
```

Define a function to access the `timestamp` function of a `datetime.datetime` object:

```
def dt_to_timestamp():
    def _dt_to_timestamp(dt):
        return int(dt.timestamp() * 1000)
    return func.udf(_dt_to_timestamp)
```

Apply that function:

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('dt_ts', dt_to_timestamp()(func.col('dt')))
>>> df.show(5, False)
+---------------------+-------------+
|dt                   |dt_ts        |
+---------------------+-------------+
|2018-01-17 19:00:15.0|1516237215000|
|2018-01-17 19:00:16.0|1516237216000|
+---------------------+-------------+

>>> df.dtypes
[('dt', 'timestamp'), ('dt_ts', 'string')]
```

I'm not sure why this column defaults to `string` when the inner `_dt_to_timestamp` function returns an `int`, but let's try to cast these "string-integers" to `IntegerType`s:

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('dt_ts', func.col('dt_ts').cast(IntegerType()))
>>> df.show(5, False)
+---------------------+-----+
|dt                   |dt_ts|
+---------------------+-----+
|2018-01-17 19:00:15.0|null |
|2018-01-17 19:00:16.0|null |
+---------------------+-----+

>>> df.dtypes
[('dt', 'timestamp'), ('dt_ts', 'int')]
```

This seems to be only an issue for `IntegerType` coercion. For `DoubleType`s, the conversion works, but I'd prefer integers...

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('dt_ts', dt_to_timestamp()(func.col('dt')))
>>> df = df.withColumn('dt_ts', func.col('dt_ts').cast(DoubleType()))
>>> df.show(5, False)
+---------------------+--------------+
|dt                   |dt_ts         |
+---------------------+--------------+
|2018-01-17 19:00:15.0|1.516237215E12|
|2018-01-17 19:00:16.0|1.516237216E12|
+---------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `IntegerType` can't store numbers as big as you're trying to convert. Use the `bigint/long` type instead:

```
>>> df = df.withColumn('dt_ts', dt_to_timestamp()(func.col('dt')))
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+-------------+
|                  dt|        dt_ts|
+--------------------+-------------+
|2018-01-17 19:00:...|1516237215000|
|2018-01-17 19:00:...|1516237216000|
+--------------------+-------------+

>>> df = df.withColumn('dt_ts', func.col('dt_ts').cast('long'))
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+-------------+
|                  dt|        dt_ts|
+--------------------+-------------+
|2018-01-17 19:00:...|1516237215000|
|2018-01-17 19:00:...|1516237216000|
+--------------------+-------------+

>>> df.dtypes
[('dt', 'timestamp'), ('dt_ts', 'bigint')]
```